# theintern test framework - testing iframes

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, intern

im creating a platform to user automated tests to verify if a widget is functional. I already made the [tutorials](https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial) and the saw the [examples](https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples) but still i can figure out what's happening.

the widget that im trying to test is made with iframes without src attribute and with im trying to find a element inside of that iframe without src attribute.`define(function (require) {
    var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');

```
registerSuite({
    name: 'index',

    'greeting form': function () {
        return this.remote
            .get(require.toUrl('localhost:3000'))
            .findById('iframeId')
            .switchToFrame('iframeId')
            .findById('buttonID');

    }
});
```

});`

With this code it happens that the intern runner returns a error saying that it wasn't unable to find the element. But when i try to run the same code on a iframe with a "src" attribute it finds the correct element and doesn't returns any error.

anyone could help ??

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you should clear the search context before trying to find an element in the iframe, like:

```
return this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl('localhost:3000'))
    .findById('iframeId')
    .end()
    .switchToFrame('iframeId')
    .findById('buttonID')
```

This is assuming the `findById` call is to wait for the iframe to be added to the page. If you don't need to do that, just leave out the `findById('iframeId')` call and you should be good.